# How to pivot partitioned table

Tags: kdb

Since you can't use exec on partitioned tables, how can they be pivoted?

Code I used to pivot in-memory table as seen on kx https://code.kx.com/q/kb/pivoting-tables/

`exec P#(p!v) by k:k from t`

```
k   v
1   10  0N  0N
2   40  20  0N
3   0N  50  30
```

This is what I want ^.

But since I have to use select on partitioned tables, the output I get from `select P#(p!v) by k:k from t`

```
k    v
1   `s#`xx`yy`zz!10 0N 0N
2   `s#`xx`yy`zz!40 20 0N
3   `s#`xx`yy`zz!0N 50 30
```

How can I convert this 2nd result into the first result without using exec initially/loading the whole table into memory? Also since symbols are enumerated, do they have to be converted to be columns?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can exec after a select, and yes you should unenumerate.

```
P:value exec distinct p from select p from pivotTab where date=...
exec P#(p!v) by k:k from select k,p,v from pivotTab where date=...
```

To clarify - your `P` should be unenumerated